# Longitude latitude for each pixel of Tiff Image

Tags: geotiff-tiff, latitude-longitude, pixel

I have a project to do and at the moment i have 2 tif images and their geografic data(longitude latitude) of their upper left pixel.What i want to do is get the common geografic place of the 2 images...so i want to get lonitude,latitude so that i can only keep the parts of the images that show the same geografic place.

The 2 images show deferent information for that place...for example the first one i a simple image and the second one shows the humidity level.
I want first to find the common place for each picture so that later i make the pictures to have the same width and length so that i can go back and forth on these 2 pictures looking at the same place but different information.

So, is my idea of finding the common place by each pixel'l geodata a good idea?

if yes...how would i do that?

if no...how should i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the coordinates for your pixels, I'll assume that your data are georeferenced.

In general the workflow would go like this:

1) **Create a shapefile containing the common area**. You can do that manually by using any gis software package, or programmatically by using the BBoxes of your datasets. 
2) Use that shapefile to **cookie-cut** your datasets to these extensions. Either again manually or programmatically

If you don't want to create a shapefile you can use some kind of pixel calculation to create a mask for the common area. (Tip: The common area have valid pixel values)

Comment: i dont think there is a problem on creating a shape file, i think i could do that.Because i want to do it programmaticly,do you have any libraries in mind that would help me to follow this workflow...from my little search i see that archGis is used as well as qGis...will some of these tools help me? I am currently thinking of doing it in java but if there is an easier way i would be open to check it out.